# What is the time complexity of the nested loop ($j=i \ldots n$ inside $i=1 \ldots n$)?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, loops

I am looking for the time complexity of the following nested loops, where the inner loop is shrinking.

```
function(int n){
  c=0;
  for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    for(int j=i;j<=n;j++)
      c++;
}
```

Comment: Have you at least run it? Maybe insert some printfs? Have you wrote it as sum? What is the question anyway?

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Your question is a very basic one. Please show your [attempts to solve it on your own](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594). Also please see [one](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/23593/4911) of our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599).

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just do your (home-)work for you; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]? You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/).

Comment: There are also many examples via [tag:algorithm-analysis+loops].

Answer (score 3):

It's not hard to see how many times `c` gets incremented.  Each $+$ in the table below represents one `c++` operation.

$$\begin{array}{r|ccccccc}
      &i=1&2&3&4&5&6&\cdots&n \\
\hline \\
   j=1&  +&+&+&+&+&+&\cdots&+& \\
     2&   &+&+&+&+&+&\cdots&+& \\
     3&   & &+&+&+&+&\cdots&+& \\
     4&   & & &+&+&+&\cdots&+& \\
     5&   & & & &+&+&\cdots&+& \\
     6&   & & & & &+&\cdots&+& \\
\vdots&   & & & & & &\ddots&+& \\
     n&   & & & & & &      &+& \\
\end{array}$$

The total number of $+$ operations is

$$\begin{align}
1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots + n =&\ \frac{n (n + 1)}{2} \\
                       =&\ \frac{n^2}{2} + \frac{n}{2}
\end{align}$$

… which is roughly $\dfrac{n^2}{2}$, which is usually just characterized as $O(n^2)$.  You can also see that roughly half of the $n \times n$ square is filled in.

Comment: Better I amend my question: actually wanted to calculate No of time the code c++ run in nested loop.

Comment: better this way I should write code again

Comment: Please consider not to encourage [undesirable posting behaviour](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594).

Comment: Since you do not count *all* operations, you need to be careful with your conclusions. Also, $O(n^2)$ is weaker than what you prove; you actually show that there are $\Theta(n^2)$ incrementations of `c`.